# Tool for creating 3D Planet terrain with editing

Tags: 3d, landscape

I am planning to create a 3D model of a specific planet/world that exists only on map. I need it to have Terrain (with texture relative to height of the terrain) and Water. Foliage would be great but its optional. Its a personal project not commercial.

I am looking for a software that allows user to create large 3D terrain of the size of raughly 1000x1000 kilometers relative to the scaling of the 3D world. The detail of planet does not have to be for a human POV. But should give a reasonable detail for a bit zoomed out isometric view, imagine a view from hot air balloon. Terrain should be created using heightmaps and then editable by hand. Important feature is the abbility to edit terrain with a brush tool (or similar tools) by hand (water, hights, depths and basic foliage). It should not be based only on proceduaral generation since I need to create a specific world, not generic one.

This is exactly what I am looking for, but I think this software is accessable only as preview but not with the editing options shown in the video: 
https://youtu.be/ggLYTGLS1tk?t=344

This Module in Unity is close to what I am looking for, but it lacks the ability to edit terrain by hand (brush tool):
https://assetstore.unity.com/package...terrain-101118

It does not need to be a planet, it can be a planet sized ladscape.

Comment: Did you go through [possible relevant questions on this site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+terrain)?

Comment: If nothing of those fits: What OS should it run on? What is your price margin if it comes to paid software?

Comment: Os (windows 7 or 10). As for the specs its should run on GTX 970 GPU and i7-4790K CPU. Which is more than what is shown on the video of software in my post. 
I could pay up to 1000$, but it depends on hhow much it delivers of what I need.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - I use Unity and several plugins for world building:
Gaia, CTS (Complete Terrain Shader, Aquas, and Enviro Sky.

For what you're asking, Gaia and CTS alone could do what you need.

[Gaia](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/terrain/gaia-42618)

[CTS](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/terrain/cts-complete-terrain-shader-91938)

there is a learning curve to each of these, but when used together, they are wicked effective and powerful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90nAHjh2abk

[image]